# Return location of value from a sorted list

Tags: python

I hope I'm describing this correctly:  I am looking to update the state of an object based upon the object's current state, a transition matrix, and a random variable ("rv").

As an illustration, suppose I have a matrix of N elements with three states (say, Solid, Liquid, Gas).    Each  state has it's own probability of changing states.   A 'threshold value' when compared to a rv determines the state.

Eg,

```
         Solid     Liquid       Gas
Solid    .50        .75          1.00

Liquid   .25        .50          1.00

Gas      .15        .35          1.00
```

I would like to write a function which given this transition matrix, a current state, and an rv, returns the new state in as efficient a manner as possible (I am running many simulations, and the actual matrix is much larger than 3x3).

Here's my code, where 'value' is the rv, and 'list' is a sorted list of a selected row containing the values expressed above.  EG, for "Solid" the list is:

[.50,.75,1.0]

```
def return_location(value, list):
 # Returns location i from sorted list where value is >= i and < i+1
 len = length(list)
 for i in range(0,(len-1)):
     if value < list[i]
         return(i)
         break;
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: But how would the logic work to select the attribute?

Comment: Sorry, either I don't understand, or wasn't being clear:  I want to select a new state which is a function of its current state by reference to an RV.  Eg, if the current state was "Solid" and the RV (U[0,1)) was 0.8, then the new state would be "Gas." Not sure how to do this without a loop, which I don't think is Pythonic - or efficient.

Comment: Have started to make a function that demonstrates further what you are wanting to do? I don't understand the terminology you are using, such as RV - is that short for Reference Value? What field of study/work is this in, e.g. physics? Is there any documentation/online references you could link to that is an example or explains these concepts further? Sorry, just trying to help until someone else comes along. thanks.

Comment: @downshift The application is finance but I chose a Physics example as it was concise.   "RV" is random variable.   Code snippet included.

Comment: Are you applying the transition matrix to many states simultaneously? Are you applying it repeatedly? Do you know how many times that you will need to apply it?

Comment: What I am trying to get at is: There is probably a linear algebra approach, possibly using Markov chains and diagonalization/exponentiation, that would be much more efficient than what it seems like you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), it is available in module [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) as `bisect` function

```
import bisect
l = [2,4,6,8,9,10]

bisect.bisect(l, 3)
>>> 1
```

it can return more than len(l) if the number is larger than the last element, but that can be solved easily with a check

```
bisect.bisect(l, 10)
>>> 6
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work.   I'll benchmark it against my function and report back.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but here's a quick way to use `numpy.random.multinomial` to apply each of your transition rows onto a state vector containing the population.

```
import numpy as np

transition = [
    [0.50, 0.25, 0.25],
    [0.25, 0.25, 0.50],
    [0.15, 0.35, 0.50]
]

state = [10, 20, 30] # 10 solid, 20 liquid, 30 gas

def update_state(state, transition):
    return sum(np.random.multinomial(s, r) for s, r in zip(state, transition))

print update_state(state, transition) # [12 17 31] - 12 solid, 17 liquid, 31 gas
```

Comment: Not sure if I specified the problem clearly enough - I'm only looking at a "State" as a boolean, not a value.

Comment: @GPB Yeah, I'm not really what your asking. This is equivalent to running 60 simulations with the starting states specified in `state` and accumulating the results. Since you said that you are running many simulations, it's likely that there is a elegant way to do them in parallel.